# Android ScreenLock event?

Tags: java, android, events, screen

i'm an IT Student and the language i'm learning is C#, it's quite similar to Java so I gave Android programming a shot. But I have a question:
Is there and event that's fired when the screen is (un)locked?
And if possible, can someone show me a code snippet showing an action done when the screen is (un)locked?

Answer (score 4):

This article [Handling Screen OFF and Screen ON Intents](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/) has code snippets for handling ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and ACTION_SCREEN_ON intents.

Comment: Would I be able to "perform actions" using only the first 2 code snippets?

Comment: For the record -- lock off/on is not the same event as screen off/on.